# Using SOAP to access webservices - failing on soapclient()

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I'm receiving the following error when using soapclient($myUrl);

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL

Here is what I see if a directly access the WSDL link.

http://services" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://services" xmlns:intf="http://services" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns1="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    
    
        http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            http://services"/>
            http://rpc.xml.coldfusion"/>
            http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

```
                <element name = "key" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                <element name = "value" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name = "Map">
            <sequence>
                <element maxOccurs = "unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="apachesoap:mapItem"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>

    </schema>
    <schema targetNamespace = "http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import namespace = "http://services"/>
        <import namespace = "http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
        <import namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <complexType name = "CFCInvocationException">
            <sequence/>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name = "QueryBean">

            <sequence>
                <element name = "columnList" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string"/>
                <element name = "data" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOfArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
    <schema targetNamespace = "http://services" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import namespace = "http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
        <import namespace = "http://rpc.xml.coldfusion"/>

        <import namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <complexType name = "ArrayOf_xsd_anyType">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base = "soapenc:Array">
                    <attribute ref = "soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"/>
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name = "ArrayOf_xsd_string">

            <complexContent>
                <restriction base = "soapenc:Array">
                    <attribute ref = "soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name = "ArrayOfArrayOf_xsd_anyType">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base = "soapenc:Array">

                    <attribute ref = "soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[][]"/>
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name = "updateCampaignResponse">

    <wsdl:part name = "updateCampaignReturn" type="xsd:boolean"/>

</wsdl:message>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first part of that WSDL is chopped off.. was that just a copy/paste error, or is that actually what you got back?

If that's actually what you got back, then there's your problem right there.  For some reason you're only getting the "tail end" of the WSDL.